# Find new (X,Y) after resizing and cropping image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a image that has to be cropped around a bounding box and resized to 256x256. In my original image I have an number of Points (x,y) that are in the bounding box.

This is my original image with my original coordinates marked:

[image]

Heres the cropped result, where the red points are the right x,y and the blue ones are my current result:

[image]

Heres how I'm doing it:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def scaleBB(bb, scale):
    centerX = (bb[0][0] + bb[1][0]) / 2
    centerY = (bb[0][1] + bb[2][1]) / 2
    center = (centerX, centerY)
    scl_center = (centerX * scale[0], centerY * scale[1])

    p1 = scale * (bb[0] - center) + scl_center
    p2 = scale * (bb[1] - center) + scl_center
    p3 = scale * (bb[2] - center) + scl_center
    p4 = scale * (bb[3] - center) + scl_center

    return np.array([p1, p2, p3, p4])


def expandBB(scaledBB, size):
    bbw = np.abs(scaledBB[0][0] - scaledBB[1][0])
    bbh = np.abs(scaledBB[0][1] - scaledBB[2][1])

    expandX = (size[0] - bbw) / 2
    expandY = (size[1] - bbh) / 2

    p1 = scaledBB[0] + (-expandX, -expandY)
    p2 = scaledBB[1] + (+expandX, -expandY)
    p3 = scaledBB[2] + (+expandX, +expandY)
    p4 = scaledBB[3] + (+expandX, +expandY)

    return np.array([p1, p2, p3, p4])

def recalculate_joints_points(oldX, oldY, newX, newY, joints):
    R_x = newX / oldX
    R_y = newY / oldY

    new_joints = []

    for index, joint in enumerate(joints):
        x = joint[0]
        y = joint[1]

        n_x = round(R_x * x)
        n_y = round(R_y * y)

        print(R_x, R_y, x, y, n_x, n_y)

        new_joints.append([n_x, n_y])

    return np.array(new_joints)

def cropAndResizeImage(label, bb):
    img_path = "original.jpg"
    # downscale
    image = cv2.imread(img_path)
    # orgSize = image.shape[:2]
    label = label
    bb = bb
    print(bb)
    dim = int(256 / 2)
    # define the target height of the bounding box
    targetHeight = 200.0
    w = np.abs(bb[0][0] - bb[1][0])
    h = np.abs(bb[0][1] - bb[2][1])
    targetScale = targetHeight / h
    print(targetScale)

    scaledImage = cv2.resize(image, (0, 0), fx=targetScale, fy=targetScale)
    scaledBB = scaleBB(bb, (targetScale, targetScale))
    cropRegion = expandBB(scaledBB, (256, 256))
    print(scaledBB)

    print(cropRegion)

    startX = int(cropRegion[0][0] + dim)
    startY = int(cropRegion[0][1] + dim)
    endX = startX + 256  # cropRegion[2][0] + dim
    endY = startY + 256  #cropRegion[2][1] + dim
    print(startX, startY, endX, endY)

    padded_image = np.pad(scaledImage, ((dim, dim), (dim, dim), (0, 0)), mode='constant')
    croppedImage = padded_image[startY:endY, startX:endX]

    # new label
    print(image.shape, croppedImage.shape)
    oldWidth = image.shape[1]
    oldHeight = image.shape[0]
    newWidth = 256 + dim
    newHeight = 256 + dim

    out_label = recalculate_joints_points(oldWidth, oldHeight, newWidth, newHeight, label)

    return [croppedImage, out_label]        

def main():
    labels = np.array([[1214, 598],
                        [1169, 424],
                        [1238, 273],
                        [1267, 285],
                        [1212, 453],
                        [1229, 622],
                        [1253, 279],
                        [1173, 114],
                        [1171, 113],
                        [1050, 60],
                        [1106, 143],
                        [1140, 100],
                        [1169, 80],
                        [1176, 148],
                        [1152, 280],
                        [1087, 391]])

    bb = np.array([[1050, 60],
                    [1267, 60],
                    [1267, 622],
                    [1050, 622]])

    img, label = cropAndResizeImage(labels, bb)

    for point in label:
        print(point)
        x,y = point
        cv2.circle(img,(int(x),int(y)),5,(255,0,0),-11)

    cv2.imshow("cropped", img)
    cv2.waitKey()    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As far as I understood is to get the new (x,y) you have to calculate the ratio (difference of size in a scale factor) but it still seems off. Any help is appreciated.

*EDIT 1:*

Using as newHeight/Width just 256 produces this image:

[image]

*EDIT 2:

Using solution of @ChrisH its quite perfect but still a little bit off:

[image]

Comment: I'm scaling down without stretching the image

Comment: ah right-o then

Comment: your bounding box isn't square and it doesn't look like you are accounting for it.  I'd make that square and get that working before trying with a skinny bounding box.

Comment: @ChrisH can you explain why that would help me?

Comment: Perform the same transformations on those points as you do with the coordinates of the bounding box corners. Follow that by translation to match any cropping/padding you do.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that @DanMašek

Comment: handling the scaling is most easily done by using pixel coordinates relative to the image size (values in.ranfe 0..1). But you will have to care about the cropping.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a function that will translate directly from the original coordinates into the cropped and scaled coordinates. You can skip all the other functions and transform points directly with this

```
def getNewCoords(x,y):
    bbUpperLeftX = bb[0][0]
    bbUpperLeftY = bb[0][1] 
    bbLowerRightX = bb[2][0] 
    bbLowerRightY = bb[2][1] 

    sizeX = bbLowerRightX - bbUpperLeftX
    sizeY =  bbLowerRightY - bbUpperLeftY

    sizeMax = max(sizeX, sizeY)

    centerX = (bbLowerRightX + bbUpperLeftX)/2
    centerY = (bbLowerRightY + bbUpperLeftY)/2

    offsetX = (centerX-sizeMax/2)*256/sizeMax
    offsetY = (centerY-sizeMax/2)*256/sizeMax

    x = x * 256/sizeMax - offsetX 
    y = y * 256/sizeMax - offsetY
    return (x,y)
```

Comment: I'm sorry but your solution works perfectly! My targetHeight was at 200. Its now at 256 and all points are transformed right!

Answer (score 1):

Since you define

```
endX = startX + 256
endY = startY + 256
```

And make the output image as

```
croppedImage = padded_image[startY:endY, startX:endX]
```

Shouldn’t the new width and height be 256? instead you define them as

```
newWidth = 256 + dim
newHeight = 256 + dim
```

I think `dim` is unnecessary here

Comment: still not at that position

Comment: Ah sorry! I'll try to find other causes then

Answer (score 0):

You can use **augmentit** to do the task.

```
    pip install augmentit
```

Documentation
link : https://github.com/sandesha-hegde/augmentit